# return many to many relation result in laravel and return null if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have a relation between tables subjects and teachers (many to many)

| subjects |
| --- |
| id |
| title |

| teachers |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| subject_teacher |
| --- |
| id |
| subject_id |
| teacher_id |
| semester_id |

this is my code with foreach and it return null if it doesn't exist

```
 $subjects = Subject:all();
 foreach ($subjects as $subject){
            $subject->staff = $subject->staffSubjects()->wherePivot('semester_id',$semester->id)->first();
        }
```

is there a way to get the staff of each subject with eloquent in one line without a loop and if it doesn't exist  return null ?

Answer (score 0):

Has
has() is to filter the selecting model based on a relationship. So it acts very similarly to a normal WHERE condition. If you just use has('relation') that means you only want to get the models that have at least one related model in this relation.

Example:

User > hasMany > Post

$users = User::has('posts')->get()

Comment: i want to return the subjects with the teacher  if there is a teacher attached to it in this semester while in your case it will only return the teachers that has subjects\